# CAN/FD over UTP / modular connector

Tags: can

Is it possible to run a CAN/FD bus over UTP (CAT 5+)?

If so, are there conventions for which modular connector pins to use?

Comment: It might be possible, but is it allowed by the specs? What would you do to the mismatch of the bus characteristic impedance? CAN requires 120 ohms bus and termination, your CAT5 cabling is 100 ohms.

Comment: I would guess it might be possible to simply adjust the bus terminators to 100 ohms to match the cable.    I'm not sure that's a big deal to the transceivers.

Comment: I find references saying: "[Increasingly, RJ45 connectors are used for CAN communication. The pinning is also recommended in CiA 303-1.](https://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/can/systemdesign-can-physicallayer/#:~:text=The%20pinning%20is%20also%20recommended%20in%20CiA%20303-1.,to%20submit%20the%20desired%20pin%20assignment%20to%20CiA.)"  Does anyone have access to that spec?

Comment: The CANopen spec is actually quite flexible when it comes to termination, allowing different values depending on bus length, mOhm/m and diameter. CiA 303-1 gives some examples on page 7. Now what CAN transceivers can handle is another story, I suppose different kinds may be more or less picky with impedance.

Comment: @Burt_Harris Remember that simply using an RJ45 (actually, their real name are 8P8C) or any other connector does not mean using 100 ohm CAT5 wiring, the wiring could still be standard 120 ohm CAN wiring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISO standard for "high speed CAN" doesn't cover connectors. Therefore the CANopen standards have become the most canonical source instead. The relevant one being [CiA 303-1](https://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/canopen/cia303/), which contains standardization for RJ10, RJ45 and lots of other common connectors. You can download the document for free from the non-profit organization *CAN in Automation* that maintains CANopen, if you just register on their site.

For your convenience, here are the relevant parts from CiA 303-1:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found details for CAN pinouts at http://www.interfacebus.com/Can_Bus_Connector_Pinout.html.   These included both 4p4c and 8p8c modular connectors (sometimes misnamed RJ10 and RJ45).

For the 4p4c version, the pin assignments are

Pin 1: CAN V+,
Pin 2: CAN_H,
Pin 3: CAN_L,
Pin 4: CAN_GND

[image: 4P4C modular connectors]

Somewhat surprisingly, the pinout recommended for 8P8C does not put the same signals on the center 4 pins.

Comment: Why would RJ10 and RJ45 be "misnamed"? The proper canonical source for these pinouts is CANopen CiA 303-1 and even that one calls them RJ10 and RJ45.

Comment: @Lundin The real name for the connectors really are 4P4C and 8P8C. RJ45 is not a name for any connector, it is a name for a standardized telecommunication network interface, which defines how an 8P8C connector is used with it, but RJ45 also defines a lot of other things. RJ10 is not even a code name for any standard, but for some reason that name is applied to 4P4C connectors.

Comment: The RJ prefix stands for Registered Jack, it actually has legal/regulatory use.  The FCC regulates telephone uses under "Part 68" regulations.   When a connector is used for say ethernet, it is not used in a way that Part 68 applies.   For the Full Monty, see https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-68.

Comment: The 4P4C connector used between a telephone and it's handset is NOT subject to FCC regulation, and that's why the so-called RJ10 is not really a correct term, but people understand what you mean because it looks like a registered jack.